# Anomaly between actually rendering and previewing a post?

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

When one writes the following Markdown:

```
[Googling](http://google.com/search?q="foo bar")
```

something weird happens (at least on the [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com) and [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)).

The Markdown is rendered as a link in the **preview** (underneath the edit-textarea), but when one views the question **on the page**, it is rendered like the Markdown source code.

I can understand the Markdown interpreter has problems with the spaces in the URL, these are mainly a result of a copy-paste of the *Firefox* url-bar. And when one uses the escaped version, no problems occur. The preview is probably rendered by *JavaScript* whereas the questions/answers are probably rendered at server side by a different software package.

It is however rather strange, the two versions **interpret** the *Markdown* slightly different.

Of course this is a minor *"bug"*, but as always: it is nice if the preview and the page render the same result, this saves users editing the page multiple times. Even if it only saves a second, with `1M+` users, it will save a few years of working time eventually.

**Demo**:

(hit [edit] to compare both versions)

[Googling](http://google.com/search?q="foo bar")

[Rendered correctly](http://google.com/search?q=%22foo%20bar%22)

Comment: FWIW, JavaScript actually doesn't render it correctly. It completed loses the "foo bar" on the end of the URL and only includes up to the `?q=` in the rendered link. So it chokes on it too, just in a different way.

Comment: @animuson: you are right. Although it is probably better if both renders agree on the result...

Comment: Quotation marks are not valid characters in a URL ... neither are spaces FWIW. the link you give isn't recognized as one since... well it isn't a valid link.

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow: this is indeed true (as already specified in the question). But anyway, both renderers better generate the same result. And this can be an indication for a more severe problem in the parser. I guess the *JavaScript* parser simply aims to parse anything between the square brackets and later tries to find out whether it is a valid url, where as the server-side parser parses token-by-token and when it fails to recognize the url, falls-back on the alternative of presenting the raw Markdown.